# Insert data from PHP to MySQL ONLY if multiples values don't exist in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with columns A, B, C, D, E, F

Now I'm trying to insert data from PHP into this database ONLY if the data doesn't already exist in A **AND** B **AND** E.

The data may be duplicated within columns many times but the same data in these 3 columns cannot be repeated.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: many ways of doing this, did you try/search for anything?

Comment: and what have you tried? because Stackoverflow is not "give me" a code place

Comment: My current query is just:

$sql = "INSERT INTO data (champ_id, items_bought, lane, match_id, tier, map_id, team_id) VALUES ('$championPlayed', '$listofitems', '$lane', '$matchIdArray[$i]', '$tier', '$mapId', '$teamID')";

However everything I've searched makes a column unique or only shows how to do this for one column. I need to only insert if it's unqiue in ALL 3 columns as the data may be repeated in one column and not the other. A,B,C,D,E was just a simplified version of my data.